# How to Unit Test private methods that update a database, without actually updating the database - in a WinForms VB.Net legacy code app?

Tags: database, vb.net, winforms, unit-testing, refactoring

I've started working on a legacy code (i.e. no unit tests) Windows Forms app written in VB.Net and I've been asked to start introducing unit tests as I make changes. I have not done much unit testing before and I am unsure how to test a recurring pattern I see in the methods. Here is my attempt to outline a simplified typical example:

```
Private Sub cmdButton_Click(ByVal eventSender As Object, ByVal eventArgs As EventArgs) Handles cmdAprv.Click

    'The event is Private and it then calls multiple other private methods
    'but I will simplify drastically for this example:
    If <conditions> Then
        InsertEmployee()
    End If

End Sub

Private Function InsertEmployee() As Integer

    'Typically, the functions are quite long with lot of code initializing 
    'variables, but I will simplify drastically for this example:
    Dim _name As String = "[]"
    Dim _departmenmt As String = "Engineering"
    Dim _salary As Double = 2000

    'Then at the end there may be multiple database updates like this one:

    Dim connectionString As String = "<Call a Function to get ConnectionString details>"
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Employees (Name, Department, Salary) VALUES (@Name, @Department, @Salary)", conn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", _name)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", _departmenmt)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", _salary)
            conn.Open()
            Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()
            Return i
        End Using
    End Using

End Function
```

1. There is a *lot* of code in Private methods like this. To make these methods accessible to the testing project, I reckon I can downgrade the Function's accessibility protection from Private to Friend (VB.Net “Friend” = C# “internal” access modifier) and then use `InternalsVisibleTo` Attribute to mark the unit testing assembly as a friend assembly.
2. But I’m really not sure what to do with the Database `INSERT` or `UPDATE` code to make the function testable? One requirement I have is that **the Unit Tests must not actually modify the database**.

Can anyone show me a good example of refactoring a method like this for unit testing?

Answer (score 1):

This is of course opinion-based. But here is what I do with legacy un-testable methods.

1. In your tested project, as you said, introduce `InternalsVisibleTo`
2. In your tested project introduce unit test - specific methods that will be only available for `DEBUG` configuration

```vb
#If DEBUG Then
    Friend Function InsertEmployee_UT() As Integer
        ' call your method here
    End Function
#End If
```

This is the principle. In fact, wrap your `InternalVisibleTo` with `#If DEBUG Then`

3. Build and perform your unit tests only in `DEBUG` configuration, and call the UT-functions that will not exist in `RELEASE`/Production code

Now Lets talk about breaking from the database. While calling DB can be a different sort of test, like Functional Test, you're right. Preferably, you can run your unit test without DB connection. What to do

1. Separate db calls into a single provider and pass Interface into the method. Yes, you need slight method change

```vb
 Friend Function InsertEmployee(provider As IEmployeeData) As Integer
```

With this, in your unit test you can mock your provider and then examine. You can actually set this provider during construction or a property, then you don't even need to pass it to each method.

2. You can pass a `callback As Function(Of . . )` or `callback As Action(Of . . )` 
   This way you also can separate functionality of retrieving data and calling for it.

These changes are not very intensive and can be done relatively quickly. And you will be able to do your testing. Changing private methods is safe, you can do it in any form or shape.